# Webdev Facebook API friends return an object array[1] however I cannot access it via javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I need help parsing the `friendsList` object returned by [below] into JavaScript.

```
FB.api('me/friends', function(response) {});
```

I want to parse "response" into an array
I tried `response.forEach ...`

I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: friendsObject.forEach is not a function

So I thought I could just do `JSON.parse(response);` that also gave me an error.

Then I tried to print out with `console.log(response)` as it gives me an Object.

I am super confused why the object cant turn into an array, wont parse but prints the entire object when I console.log it.

How do I parse that object into a javascript array?

Comment: You don't need to parse anything - you just need to access the correct property in the object, that holds the _data_ ...

Answer (score 0):

Always use `console.log` to see the actual content of the `response` object. It is usually an object with a "data" array, so it would be like this:

```
response.data.forEach...
```

Do not forget about error handling, `response.data` can be undefined too.